# Tagging inside Text Area in React Bootstrap 3

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, reactjs, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm looking to be able to implement some sorta tagging (or use a library) inside a text area in React.

I"m currently using react-bootstrap components and I have a component like so

```
<FormGroup>
  <ControlLabel className="additem-label">{props.labelTitle}</ControlLabel>
  <FormControl type="text" placeholder={props.placeHolderText} onChange={(event) => props.updateData(props.formType, event)}  />
</FormGroup>
```

Since the tags would have to go inside the FormControl but this is a created library, is there anyway I can add some form of jquery tagging inside of it?  (https://bootstrap-tagsinput.github.io/bootstrap-tagsinput/examples/)

I'm stuck because I"m not sure how to actually add the DOM elements inside of that specific react bootstrap component since I don't know it's structure.

Answer (score 0):

`Bootstrap Tags Input` is a jQuery plugin,
you can use some react based library like [react-tag-autocomplete](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-tag-autocomplete).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this React package can help you. https://github.com/prakhar1989/react-tags

Also this is a good option too
https://github.com/olahol/react-tagsinput